# How to migrate code to different Visual Studio Online project?

Tags: azure, tfs, migration, azure-devops, tfs-process-template

I have my Visual Studio C# source code inside Microsoft Azure - Visual Studio Online (VSO), which is basically Team Foundation Server (TFS) 2013 in a Cloud. The Project was created using Microsoft Visual Studio Scrum 2013.3 Process Template.

I need to change process template from current (Scrum) to native Microsoft Visual Studio Agile 2013.3 Process Template.

Currently I do have only source code inside VSO and need to preserve all versions/check ins, with date/times and owners for whole team, there are NO any work items (tasks, bugs etc.)

One solution is to open a new Project inside VSO with Agile template, however how to migrate my code? or how to make simple / easy changes to current VSO project to change process template?

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a new project and branch your code to the new project. The old project must remain to maintain history
2. use the TFS Integration tools to replay history against the new location.
3. (recommended) Switch to Git and use Git-TF to pull the history into git.
4. check out the tip and check into the new project.

The only option here that adds future value is to move to Git. Once there your history will be forever portable.

Comment: I was thinking about Git on TFS however it implements different logic and branching technics, also Visual Studio 2013.3 currently does not work very will with native/external non-ms git.exe client/solution, so I will probably avoid git for now. Do you have any free solution for migration?

Comment: You can do #1 or #2. Both of which are free